# Rails find_by_sql with same field names in select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to run next code in Rails:

```
boatData = Boat.find_by_sql(["SELECT bm.name as name1, bt.name as name2 
                                  FROM boat_models bm, boat_types bt, boats b
                                  WHERE b.id = ?
                                  AND bm.id = b.boat_model_id
                                  AND bt.id = bm.boat_type_id", boatId]).first
    puts "boatData=" + boatData.inspect
    description = "Booking: " + boatData[:name1] + "(" + boatData[:name2].to_s + ")"
```

The only problem is the fields in the select have the same name. When I try to add "as" the results are not right.

**UPDATE:**

This it the output of  puts "boatData=" + boatData.inspect

```
boatData=#<BoatModel id: nil, name: "Velero">
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not right"?

Comment: See my updated comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be very wrong, but it looks like you just want to select a `Boat` and then get the model and type name for that boat.

If I understand your data model correctly, you can use:

```
boat = Boat.find(boatId)
modelName = boat.boat_model.name
typeName = boat.boat_model.boat_type.name
```